# How do I sort my dwellers in reverse order?

Tags: fallout-shelter

You can sort your dweller list by tapping on column headers. But it only sorts in descending order. It can be rather frustrating to scroll down to the bottom over and over, especially in a larger vault.

**How do I sort in ascending order?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You couldn't do this when the game came out, but it is a new feature as of the latest patch.

To sort in ascending order **from the dweller list, tap the arrow in the upper-left hand corner**. This will switch the sort.

This setting persists when you close and open the dweller list and when you switch sort columns, so you'll have to manually switch it back.